# Can I use a Windows -> Class Library inside a WP7 application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, class-library

I'm creating a library application that will act as a wrapper for an exposed API. This library ideally should work on any desktop application, but truth be told I'm intending to use this on the WP7 once I'm done creating the library.

Would this work?

Comment: All .NET assemblies are compiled against a specific mscorlib. You can't reference a .NET assembly compiled against, say, the Silverlight mscorlib, in a non-Silverlight application. So the question is: Which mscorlib is shipped with Windows Phone 7? Silverlight? The full desktop .NET Framework? .NET Compact Framework? Or a new, Windows Phone 7-specific flavour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/devices/windows-phone/):

> Silverlight is the application development platform for Windows Phone 7. High performance gaming is also supported through the XNA Framework.

You can't reference a .NET assembly which was compiled against the full .NET Framework in a Silverlight application.

Develop your library for Silverlight and all should be fine.

Comment: But you can share the source code fairly easily, if there's no interop, or dependency on other libraries which you cant compile on silverlight...